# Fit Matplotlib 3D subplot to figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a minimum example of my code as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(16, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d',elev=-150, azim=110)
 
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

If run my .py script i get following plot with a lot of white spaces on the left and right. Is it possible to fit the subplot to the defined figsize? In a previous python version there were no whitespaces, but since i use python 3.9.4 together with matplotlib 3.5.2 the subplot has white spaces on the left and right. Hope someone can help me with this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `set_box_aspect()`, you can set aspect ratio for Matplotlib 3d box, look from this [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html)

so in your case, add this line after you define ax (before plt)

```
ax.set_box_aspect((20, 16, 9))
```

Comment: thank you very much. that helped me a lot. i could not remove all the white spaces but it looks a lot better :)